# Automate the process of logging to website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, automation

I would like to automate the process of logging to a webpage everyday.
First I want the process of entering and submitting my credentials automatically working correctly and then I'll see how I can make it run periodically with cron jobs or something like that.

Here is the source code of the page I want to login to : (https://customer.sunvalleytek.com/login)

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
<title>Sunvalley - Your Login | RAVPower, TaoTronics, HooToo, VAVA</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<!--
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KC4S8Q"></script><script type="text/javascript">
var ctxPath = '';
var brand = 'RAVPower';
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Include the FontAwesome CSS if you want to use feedback icons provided by FontAwesome -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css?v=1.0">
<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script src="/js/util.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="/js/i18n/front-lang-en.js"></script>
<script src="/js/front-base.js"></script>
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>
<link href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon">
<link href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="Shortcut Icon"><!--地址栏和标签上显示图标-->
<link href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="Bookmark"><!--收藏夹显示图标-->

<script type="text/javascript">
 var pageValidate = {
  fields:{
   email: {
    validators:{
     notEmpty: {
                     message: bootstrapValidatorMsg.required
                 },
     emailAddress: {
                     message: bootstrapValidatorMsg.email
                 }
    }
   },
   password: {
    validators:{
     notEmpty: {
                     message: bootstrapValidatorMsg.required
                 }
    }
   }
  }
 };
 var login = {
  forms:[{
   id:'loginForm',
   submit:true,
   url: '/noaccount/login',
   validate:pageValidate,
   confirmFn:function(rtmsg){
    var opt;
    if(rtmsg.SUCCESS){
     if(rtmsg.backto){
      window.location.href = ctxPath + rtmsg.backto;
     }else{
      window.location.href = ctxPath + "/account/welcome";
     }
    }else{
     $('#boxModalTitle').html(PromptMsg.prompt);
     $('#boxModalBody').html(rtmsg.MESSAGE);
     opt = function () {
     };

     $('#boxModal').modal('show');
     $('#boxModal').on('hide.bs.modal', opt);
    }
   }
  }]
 };


 var pageValidateResetPwd = {
  fields:{
   accountEmail: {
    validators:{
     /*notEmpty: {
                     message: bootstrapValidatorMsg.required
                 },
     emailAddress: {
                     message: bootstrapValidatorMsg.email
                 }*/
    }
   }
  }
 };


 var resetPwd = {
  forms:[{
   id:'resetPwdForm',
   submit:true,
   url: '/noaccount/password/reset',
   validate:pageValidateResetPwd,
   confirmFn:function(rtmsg){
    var opt;
    if(rtmsg.SUCCESS){
     $('#forgetPasswordModel').modal('hide');

     $('#boxModalTitle').html(PromptMsg.prompt);
     opt = function () {

     };
     $('#boxModalBody').html(rtmsg.MESSAGE);
     $('#boxModal').modal('show');
     $('#boxModal').on('hide.bs.modal', opt);
    }else{
     $('#msgTip').text(rtmsg.MESSAGE);
     $('#msgTip').show();
    }
   },
   beforeSendFn:function(){
    $('#msgTip').text("");
   }
  }]
 };

 $().ready(function(){
  bootValidate(login.forms);
  bootValidate(resetPwd.forms);
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
 <noscript>&lt;iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KC4S8Q"
 height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</noscript>
 <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
 new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
 j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
 '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
 })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KC4S8Q');</script>
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 login margin-t1">
           <div class="logo">
              <img src="/images/login-logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
           </div>
           <form role="form" id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal bv-form" novalidate="novalidate"><button type="submit" class="bv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="brandId" id="brandId" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="preUrl" value="null">
            <input type="hidden" name="backto" value="">
               <h5>Your session has time out, please log in again.</h5>
               <!-- email -->
               <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                 <label class="control-label">Email :</label>
                 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" placeholder="enter your e-mail" data-bv-field="email"><i class="form-control-feedback" data-bv-icon-for="email" style="display: none;"></i>
               <small class="help-block" data-bv-validator="notEmpty" data-bv-for="email" data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">This field is required.</small><small class="help-block" data-bv-validator="emailAddress" data-bv-for="email" data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">Invalid Email Address</small></div>
               <!-- end email -->

               <!-- password -->
               <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label">Password :</label>
                 <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="confirm password" data-bv-field="password"><i class="form-control-feedback" data-bv-icon-for="password" style="display: none;"></i>
                 <a class="pull-right forget" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgetPasswordModel">Forget password</a>
               <small class="help-block" data-bv-validator="notEmpty" data-bv-for="password" data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED" style="display: none;">This field is required.</small></div>
               <!-- end password -->

               <!-- sign -->
               <div class="form-group text-center">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn blue-bg" data-toggle="modal">SIGN IN</button>
                 <a class="btn blue-bg" href="/noaccount/register/init?backto=&amp;utm_source=&amp;utm_medium=&amp;utm_campaign=">Register Now</a>
               </div>
               <!-- end sign -->
           </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="forgetPasswordModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forget your password?</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p class="text-center">Please enter your email address below. Your will receive a link to reset your password.</p>
      <form role="form" id="resetPwdForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal bv-form" novalidate="novalidate"><button type="submit" class="bv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
             <span id="msgTip" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-9 red-color"></span>
             <span class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accountEmail" name="accountEmail" autocomplete="off" placeholder="user@domain.com" data-bv-field="accountEmail"><i class="form-control-feedback bv-no-label" data-bv-icon-for="accountEmail" style="display: none;"></i>
             </span>
             <span class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
               <button type="submit" class="btn org-bg">Submit</button>
             </span>
          </div>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- END modal -->

 <!-- modal box start-->
<div class="profile-modal">
 <div class="modal fade" id="boxModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="boxModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="boxModalTitle"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <h5 id="boxModalBody" style="margin-bottom:30px;"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
             <span class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
       <button type="button" class="btn org-bg" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </span>
     </div>
           </div>
    </div>
       </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- modal box end-->

</body></html>
```

I have tried to automatically enter my credentials with HTML using POST method (https://crunchify.com/automatic-html-login-using-post-method-autologin-a-website-on-double-click/) and also using a different method outlined here (https://help.risevision.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115019363963-Auto-Login-on-Webpage-using-Javascript) where I replaced the http://www.exemple.com url by https://customer.sunvalleytek.com/login but it doesn't work.
My guess is that the form type is in Javascript whereas the links just above outline how to fill an html type form. However I haven't found anything about auto-filling Javascript type forms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the code provided above, but check out Puppeteer https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer - you can use it automate the process of filling out forms. I've used it before to do remote login work. You could use it to target that form class and fill in the details and feign a click to login.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks!